# Detection of Event in R

Tags: r, detection

I have a very large data frame, with about 1000 rows and 10000 columns, every column is an ID and every row represents a date.
And every cell in the data frame can be though as the accumulated number of occurrences for a particular issues up to that date to that ID.

A simplified data is as following:

```
Date       id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
2012-01-01   0   1   0   2   1
2012-01-02   0   2   0   2   2
2012-01-03   2   2   0   8   3
2012-01-04   2   2   1   8   4
2012-01-05   2   2   1   8   5
2012-01-06   4   3   1   8   6
2012-01-07   4   5   1  14   7
2012-01-08   5   8   1  16   8
2012-01-09   5   8   1  20   9
2012-01-10   5   9   1  20  10
```

So, for the cell("2012-01-05", "id5"), it could mean that since the beginning to that date, 5 items of id5 are sold, or error id5 had occurred 5 times, something like that.

I am going to write a program to detected any unusual events and record the id, the start date and the end date of the event.
e.g, id2 has an unusual event on 2012-01-08 (2012-01-10 is not counted because increasing from 8 to 9 is not abnormal for id2);
id4 have two unusual events, one is on 2012-01-03 and the other is from 2012-01-07 to 2012-01-09

The output data would be like the following:

```
Event IDs Start_Date    End_Date  number_Unusual
    1 id2 2012-01-08  2012-01-08               5
    2 id4 2012-01-03  2012-01-03               6
    2 id4 2012-01-07  2012-01-09              12
    ....
```

number_Unusual: it is the number of occurrences during the unusual time frame.

I am using the following approach:
1. Calculated the accumulated Percentage Changes:

```
Date    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
1/1/2012    0.00    0.11    0.00    0.10    0.10
1/2/2012    0.00    0.22    0.00    0.10    0.20
1/3/2012    0.40    0.22    0.00    0.40    0.30
1/4/2012    0.40    0.22    1.00    0.40    0.40
1/5/2012    0.40    0.22    1.00    0.40    0.50
1/6/2012    0.80    0.33    1.00    0.40    0.60
1/7/2012    0.80    0.56    1.00    0.70    0.70
1/8/2012    1.00    0.89    1.00    0.80    0.80
1/9/2012    1.00    0.89    1.00    1.00    0.90
1/10/2012   1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00    1.00
```

2. Find the difference for a fixed time frame, say, 3-days difference:

```
Date    id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
1/4/2012    0.40    0.11    1.00    0.30    0.30
1/5/2012    0.40    0.00    1.00    0.30    0.30
1/6/2012    0.40    0.11    1.00    0.00    0.30
1/7/2012    0.40    0.33    0.00    0.30    0.30
1/8/2012    0.60    0.67    0.00    0.40    0.30
1/9/2012    0.20    0.56    0.00    0.60    0.30
1/10/2012   0.20    0.44    0.00    0.30    0.30
```

3. So far, I have arrived here, and the next step I am going to find out any unusual large value so it could be possible that there is a unusual event. I know I can use some for-loop to do my task, say, for id2, i know it is not usual for it to have a increment larger than 0.2, so:

```
event <- c(0)
ids   <- c(0)
start <- c("")
end   <- c("")
for (id in c(id1:id5))
  for (date in 2012-01-04:2012-01-10)
    if value[date, id] > 0.2
      event <- event + 1 
      ids[event] <- id
      start[event] <- date
      end[event]   <- 2012-01-10
      for (date2 in date:2012-01-10)
         if value[date2, id] <= 0.2 {
            end[event]   <- date2
            skip
         }
```

Sorry if the above pseudo-code have any mistakes, I just want to show my idea.

And now my question is, instead of using this stupid for-loop, can you suggest any smart algorithm so that I can do the same task, i.e., find all unusual events in the data set.

And also, I know my approach on using the accumulated percentage is not a very good way, if you have any other suggestion,  I am also willing to listen and learn from you.
Thank you!

Comment: I do not understand your definition of an unusual event and cannot pick out unusual events in your first example data set.  In other words, I do not understand what the numbers are in your top data set or why they change the way they do.  Perhaps clarify that.

Comment: @MarkMiller
Thank for your comment. for unusual, I mean some sudden jump in the accumulated number. say for id5, it dont have any unusual, because the number there increased one every day. But in id2 and id4, I say it is unusual because on some of the date, the number increased a lot. e.g. for id2, it suddenly doubled on 2012-01-08.
is it help explaining this?

Comment: Maybe the above example is not meaningful enough, but given that there are 1000 row, it would be enough for me to generate a "Usual" case for every id, and since that I can spot the "unusual" ones

Comment: How big does the increase have to be for each of the five columns to qualify as unusual?

Comment: I am now using a arbitrary number, say, 20%, but i think I can calculate a more reliable number for each id from the data.
It will be my next step though.

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify your code by converting your data to a `matrix`, then using `apply()` to get the running fractions and `diff()` to calculate the differences.

Recreate your data:

```
x <- read.table(tex='
Date       id1 id2 id3 id4 id5
2012-01-01   0   1   0   2   1
2012-01-02   0   2   0   2   2
2012-01-03   2   2   0   8   3
2012-01-04   2   2   1   8   4
2012-01-05   2   2   1   8   5
2012-01-06   4   3   1   8   6
2012-01-07   4   5   1  14   7
2012-01-08   5   8   1  16   8
2012-01-09   5   8   1  20   9
2012-01-10   5   9   1  20  10
', header=TRUE)
```

Then set up a function to do the differencing:

```
foo <- function(x, periods=3, exception=0.1){
  xm <- as.matrix(x)
  xp <- apply(xm, 2, function(z)z/tail(z, 1))
  diff2 <- diff(diff(xp, periods), 1)
  NAs <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(x), nrow=3)
  rbind(NAs, abs(diff2) > exception)
}
```

And you get:

```
foo(x[, -1], periods=3, exception=0.2)

        id1   id2   id3   id4   id5
 [1,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [2,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [3,]    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Edit**

To find out `which` elements are true, wrap your results in another `apply()` with `paste()` and `which()`:

```
z <- foo(x[, -1], periods=3, exception=0.2)
apply(z, 2, function(x)paste(which(x), collapse="_"))

    id1     id2     id3     id4     id5 
    "8"   "6_7"     "6" "5_6_9"      ""
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I may have stated my question unclear. I have already get the result from the foo-function. My question here is how i can summarize it, i.e., [6:7, id2] have a unusual event, so the out put data should have a row like this:
    **event# id start_date end_date related occurrence**;
    **1 id2 6 7 6**;